# Is there an equivalent of Haskell's CHP for Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, clojure, core.async

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) has this [amazing library](http://clojure.com/blog/2013/06/28/clojure-core-async-channels.html) implementing [Tony Hoare's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare) [Communicating Sequential Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) called [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async).

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) appears to have an equivalent called [chp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/chp). ([Not sure if it compiles under GHC 7.8](https://twitter.com/mimblewabe/status/493735654166372352)).

My question is **Is there an equivalent of Haskell's CHP for Scala?**

Comment: As Scala can use java library , maybe you can use JCSP : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP#Using_JCSP_from_Other_Languages . However, if you want to do concurrent programming in Scala, using Akka : http://akka.io/ , which implements Actor model, might be a good choice.

Comment: @ymonad referring to a general Akka when OP asks for a specific framework doesn't make much sense, especially given that [CSP and Actor model have fundamental differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes#Comparison_with_the_Actor_Model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/NljrQ4Mc-aI/3ISm68sqLNAJ

It provides a really interesting list of alternatives for doing CSP in Scala and doesn't recommend [JCSP](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/) since it's development apparently stopped in 2011.

It also talks about a really [interesting paper](http://wotug.org/papers/CPA-2013/Bate13/Bate13.pdf) written by Andrew Bate at Oxford that describes a DSL in Scala for CSP but that whose implementation hasn't been open sourced.

It finally describes [Quasar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) that seems the best alternative. If you're interested in Quasar, [this](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2013/05/02/quasar-pulsar/) post gives a good description of how Quasar works.